# Trouble adding feature to recursive Fibonacci program

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm working with a basic Python MIT free courseware and I have run into a wall with a recursion exercise. The original program takes an integer and provides its Fibonacci using recursion. The book provides the script for the program, but the subsequent exercise asks to input a way for the program to recognize how many times `fib(2)` is executed on its way to calculating `fib(n)`. I'm hoping to get some help because I've been stuck on this for about a week now.

Here is the code:

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
    if n ==0 or n==1:
        return n        
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', fib(i))

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is',fib(x))
print(testfib(x))
```

Reference: *Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python*, Figure 4.7

Comment: Increase a global variable when `n == 2`

Comment: A global counter is fine. But to keep with the spirit of the exercise, use an accumulator variable in your recursive function.

Answer (score 3):

Include the counter inside the function itself and let it return two values (the fibonacci value and the count). This saves you from having to manually do the business logic of resetting the count. You can call the function as many times as you want and the counts will be correct, rather than summing counts from every time *ever* that `fib` was called.

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns the nth Fibonacci number and number of times it was called"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n, 0
    else:
        f1, count1 = fib(n-1)
        f2, count2 = fib(n-2)
        sum_counts = count1 + count2
        if n == 2:
            sum_counts = 1
        return f1 + f2, sum_counts


def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        f, count = fib(i)
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', f, end="\t")
        print('count of fib(2) is ', count)

x = int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is', fib(x)[0])
print(testfib(x))
```

The output is:

```
Enter a number: 7
Fibonacci of 7 is 13
fib of 0 is  0  count of fib(2) is  0
fib of 1 is  1  count of fib(2) is  0
fib of 2 is  1  count of fib(2) is  1
fib of 3 is  2  count of fib(2) is  1
fib of 4 is  3  count of fib(2) is  2
fib of 5 is  5  count of fib(2) is  3
fib of 6 is  8  count of fib(2) is  5
fib of 7 is  13 count of fib(2) is  8
None
```

---

Since the problem treats the `n == 2` case differently, you can make that another base case in your recursion.

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n and number fo times it was called"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n, 0
    elif n == 2:
        return (fib(0) + fib(1)), 1
    else:
        f1, count1 = fib(n-1)
        f2, count2 = fib(n-2)
        return f1 + f2, count1 + count2
```

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. Thank you for the help and good explanation!

Comment: @Sisyphus0616 If that's the case, I encourage you to upvote and mark it with the checkbox to the left. You should also upvote other helpful responses.

Answer (score 1):

### Function Attributes

This takes advantage of a lesser-known feature of Python established by [PEP 232](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0232/) in order to avoid global variables or creating a full class. Python functions can have their own attributes, which can be used to provide the same functionality as static variables in some other languages. So, in your code you could do something like the following:

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
    if n == 2:
        try:
            fib.two_count += 1
        except AttributeError:
            fib.two_count = 1
    if n ==0 or n==1:
        return n        
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        fib.two_count = 0
        print(
            'fib of', i, 'is ', fib(i),
            'and fib(2) was called', fib.two_count, 'times'
        )

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is',fib(x))
print(testfib(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe slightly overkill, but wrapping the entire thing into a class, you can easily introduce a counter. Here you first create a callable `Fib` object called fib. When you now call `fib(x)`, the counter is set to zero in the `__call__` function, which then calls the `Fib.fib` function which does the actual work. Within the `Fib.fib` function, the counter is increased by one every time the function argument is equal to 2.

```
class Fib:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def __call__(self, n):
        self.count = 0
        return self.fib(n)

    def fib(self,n):
        """Assumes n is int > 0
        Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
        if n == 2:
            self.count += 1

        if n ==0 or n==1:
            return n        
        else:
            return self.fib(n-1) + self.fib(n-2)



fib = Fib()
x=5

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is',fib(x))
print('fib(2) was called {} times'.format(fib.count))
```

For the example argument (`x=5`), the output is:

```
Fibonacci of 5 is 5
fib(2) was called 3 times
```

Comment: For the love of Guido, why? That is total overkill. You can introduce a counter as an accumulator in the recursive function. And overriding `__call__`? Why?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It probably is, but I'm coming from an OO background and it definitely works. Also, if you use a global counter, you always have to reset it before calling the 'fib' function.

Comment: You should stop conflating OO with writing class definitions. Python is entirely object oriented. And writing the entire thing in assembly works, but that isn't a good reason to do that.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, let's just say I disagree, but this is probably not the place to go through this argument.

Answer (score 0):

There are neater ways to do this, but the simple way is to use a global variable to keep count of when `fib` is called with an arg of 2. You need to remember to reset the counter before each outermost call, though.

```
count = 0

def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
    global count
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        if n == 2:
            count += 1
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testfib(n):
    global count
    for i in range(n+1):
        count = 0
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', fib(i), ', called fib(2)', count, 'times')

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))

count = 0
print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is', fib(x), ', called fib(2)', count, 'times')
testfib(x)
```

**demo**

```
Enter a number: 7
Fibonacci of 7 is 13 , called fib(2) 8 times
fib of 0 is  0 , called fib(2) 0 times
fib of 1 is  1 , called fib(2) 0 times
fib of 2 is  1 , called fib(2) 1 times
fib of 3 is  2 , called fib(2) 1 times
fib of 4 is  3 , called fib(2) 2 times
fib of 5 is  5 , called fib(2) 3 times
fib of 6 is  8 , called fib(2) 5 times
fib of 7 is  13 , called fib(2) 8 times
```

---

A slightly better way is to use a function attribute instead of the modifiable global.

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        if n == 2:
            fib.count += 1
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        fib.count = 0
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', fib(i), ', called fib(2)', fib.count, 'times')

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))

fib.count = 0
print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is', fib(x), ', called fib(2)', fib.count, 'times')
testfib(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a mutable argument to the function that computes the actual Fibonacci Number—which it will increment each time it's called—and hiding the fact there's now an extra argument with a wrapper function that supplies it:

Here's what I mean:

```
def dofib(n, count):
    """Assumes n is int >= 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n."""
    count[0] += 1
    if n==0 or n==1:
        return n
    else:
        return dofib(n-1, count) + dofib(n-2, count)

def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int >= 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n and number of recursive calls."""
    count = [0]
    return dofib(n, count), count[0]

def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print('fib of {0} is {1[0]} (call count: {1[1]})'.format(i, fib(i)))

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))
print('Fibonacci of {0} is {1[0]} (call count: {1[1]})'.format(x, fib(x)))
testfib(x)
```

Sample output:

```
Fibonacci of 7 is 13 (call count: 41)
fib of 0 is 0 (call count: 1)
fib of 1 is 1 (call count: 1)
fib of 2 is 1 (call count: 3)
fib of 3 is 2 (call count: 5)
fib of 4 is 3 (call count: 9)
fib of 5 is 5 (call count: 15)
fib of 6 is 8 (call count: 25)
fib of 7 is 13 (call count: 41)
```