# Adding Counter to recursive Fibonacci program

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

I'm working with a basic Python MIT free courseware and I have run into a wall with a recursion exercise. The original program takes an integer and provides its Fibonacci using recursion. The book provides the script for the program, but the subsequent exercise asks to input a way for the program to recognize how many times fib(2) is executed on its way to calculating fib(n). ``

Here is the code:

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns Fibonacci Number of n"""
    if n ==0 or n==1:
        return n        
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', fib(i))

x=int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is',fib(x))
print(testfib(x))
```

There is an answer given in another thread I'm trying to wrap my head around and wondering if someone could explain how, what seems like tuples, in the else portion are serving as variables names in the below code?
reference: [Trouble adding feature to recursive Fibonacci program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333084/trouble-adding-feature-to-recursive-fibonacci-program)

```
def fib(n):
    """Assumes n is int > 0
    Returns the nth Fibonacci number and number of times it was called"""
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n, 0
    else:
        f1, count1 = fib(n-1)
        f2, count2 = fib(n-2)
        sum_counts = count1 + count2
        if n == 2:
            sum_counts = 1
        return f1 + f2, sum_counts


def testfib(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        f, count = fib(i)
        print('fib of', i, 'is ', f, end="\t")
        print('count of fib(2) is ', count)

x = int(input('Enter a number: '))

print('Fibonacci of', x, 'is', fib(x)[0])
print(testfib(x))
```

Comment: Maybe you are confused about tuple unpacking. It is described in the Python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: The `fib()` function returns a sequence of two items — a `tuple` — and they can be assigned directly into two different variables: i.e. `a, b = fib(x)`. Doing this is called "tuple unpacking".

Comment: @BurningKarl & martineau - Thank you both this answered my question and 7u5h4r's answer provide the clarity I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explaining it by each line

```
f1, count1 = fib(n-1)
```

Here fib returns `f1 + f2, sum_counts` (See in the end) so `f1 = f1 + f2` and `count1 = sum_counts`

```
f2, count2 = fib(n-2)
```

Here fib returns `f1 + f2, sum_counts` (See in the end) so `f2 = f1 + f2` and `count2 = sum_counts`

```
return f1 + f2, sum_counts
```

fib method is returning 2 values `f1 + f2, sum_counts` here so we have to unpack 2 values with the tuple or 2 variables

---

In your code, we are unpacking values by 2 variables below is an example of unpacking it by a tuple

```
def test():
    return 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
my_list = test()
for val in my_list:
    print(val)
```